# Active Directory: Viewing "Attribute Editor" after finding an account via ADUC's "Find" option

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows

When I activate the `Advanced features` (`View` -> `Advanced Features`)  and open a user's properties by navigating to their OU and right clicking the user object, I see the `Attribute Editor` tab.

However, if I search for a user (right click the domain -> `Find` -> search for the user), and double click on the user, I do not see the tab.

I cannot normally navigate to users because some OUs have too many users. Can someone suggest an alternative that allows me to view the `Attribute Editor` tab?

Comment: Holy hell, this bugs me to no end as well.  I tend to use @Shane Madden's answer, but it's still highly annoying.

Comment: Seems windows server 2003 would not shown this tab. I turned to `ADSIEdit.msc` instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd say set up a query for the user search instead of using the Find feature.  It's a few extra clicks, but gives you the Attribute Editor tab properly.

[image]

Make sure you set the query definition to the "Users..." type instead of the "Common Queries" type, so you get the right search behavior..

[image]

..and the Attribute Editor tab works on the object when opened from this view.

Comment: This does not always work. Simply use the MMC Menu item "View" -> "Advanced Features".

Comment: @Marc The premise of the question is even when that option is active, it will never show up when an object is opened from the search window.

Comment: @marc Your solution also doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a solution!

http://activedirectoryfaq.com/2014/10/ad-attribute-editor-missing-make-search-visible

Open de object after using "Find". Click the "Member of" tab. Open a group of which the object is a member. Close the object window. Locate the object in the group and double-click it. The object window should open with the "Attribute Editor" available.

Should work.

Tried it myself but I don't have an Attribute Editor available (Attribute Editor does not exist in a 2000/2003 forest).

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/6e6ef6bd-b5c9-4f16-b346-097832e3b93c/rsat-and-the-missing-attribute-editor-tab-solution?forum=winserverManagement

Answer (score 2):

You have several options.

- You can use [Softera LDAP Browser](http://www.ldapbrowser.com/info_softerra-ldap-browser.htm) for free.
- You can use [Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/) for free.
- You can use [ADExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907) for free.
- You can setup filter directly in ADUC on OU's view so it will filter out users as you need
- You can write in C++ your own property sheet host application for user object (I did before, I have source code) which can be invoked from comand line based on some parameter (sAMAccountName for example)

UPDATE:

- You can use build-in ADSI Edit MMC snapin (thank to Ryan Bolger for tip)

Comment: You forgot to include ADSI Edit which is also built-in. =)

Comment: W.r.t. the source code: sharing is caring! I'd like to see that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use dsac.exe instead of dsa.msc.  It does not have that limitation.  If you don't have to use a smart card, AD Explorer like Jim suggested is probably the way to go, otherwise it would be adsiedit.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Literally the best answer:
Install Active Directory Administrative Center and un-fustercluck your day....

[A two-click solution](https://errorexpress.com/windows-10-8-7-how-to-install-active-directory-users-computers-tools/#Active_Directory_Administrative_Center_Turn_ON_this_Windows_Feature). Type the user name in Global Search, double click the user name.

The attributes info is in the Extensions section at the bottom.

See the pics.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to use [ADExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but I found it searching for a fix to this.

My best solution here is to use two ADUC windows. One does the search with the Distinguished Name shown in the results window. Then browse to the user in the other window.
All day long I do this two step process to modify something in AD.