# How do I view extensionattribute in AD?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Using Windows Server 2008 R2.

I know that there are extensionattributes 1 - 15 available but I can't figure out a way to view / access them?

I have used both ADSI Edit and ADUC but neither seems to show them.

Comment: Yes - looking better now!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/399000/active-directory-viewing-attribute-editor-after-finding-an-account-via-aducs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're visible in ADSIEdit, or the Attribute Editor tab in ADUC with the advanced features enabled.

It sounds like you don't have the MS Exchange schema extensions installed; that's what installs those attributes into your schema.

Comment: I ran "regsvr32 schmmgmt.dll". In ADUC, I have the advanced features ticked. But I don't see them in the Attribute Editor. Should I see a list of 15 attributes? What are they called?

Comment: @nzpcmad The attributes don't exist on your user objects yet; your management tools are working just fine.  For those attributes to be present in your Active Directory schema, you need to have the Exchange schema extensions installed with the Exchange `setup /PrepareSchema`.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877014(EXCHG.140).aspx).

Comment: Thanks. As I read it, Exchange 2010 SP2 installs ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-16 - 45 and ms-exch-extension-custom-attribute-1 - 5. ms-Exch-Extension-Attribute-1 - 15 are derived from Exchange Server 2003. Does this mean that I have to purchase / install Exchange 2010? Will installing Exchange 2010 also install the Exchange 2003 attributes? Am I missing something?

Comment: @nzpcmad Yes, the Exchange schema extensions are cumulative; you'll get the modifications of all versions by installing 2010.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/399000/active-directory-viewing-attribute-editor-after-finding-an-account-via-aducs

Answer (score 1):

If you use the search button to find them the attribute tab won’t be visible even with advanced options checked.  You need to find the object in the tree and double click the object